# How to download and load file from the App directory to local

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have PDFs in my project. I want to give feature to download that file to mobile directory and load it with other apps.

Comment: not getting you properly!!!! your pdf is in your project means what ? in your app bundle ? if it's in your app bundle then why you want download it??!!!

Comment: I have attached all the PDFs with my App it is not visible to the users. So just want to copy that PDFs to the users local folder, So they can easily use it with any App

Comment: iPhones don't have a local folder, where would you copy the PDFs to? You could look into sharing via a UIActivityViewController.

Comment: Could it copy to the Document Directory ??

Comment: There are so many questions on how to save a file in app sandbox and how to get it back. Please do some research before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/RTOFiles"];;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDir])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDir withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

NSString *pdfName = @"form_1.pdf";

NSString *docPdfFilePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: pdfName];

//Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath: docPdfFilePath];

if (!success) {
    NSString *samplePdfFile  = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: pdfName];

    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath: samplePdfFile toPath: docPdfFilePath error: &error];

    if (!success)
        //              NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to copy file ‘%@’.", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSLog(@"Failed to copy %@ file, error %@", pdfName, [error localizedDescription]);
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@ File copied to %@", pdfName,documentsDir);
    }
}
else{
    NSLog(@"File already Exists !");
}
```

Comment: this will use double memory because it is in app bundle as well in docs directory. You can directly used file from app bundle. i m writing answer refer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly used your image if it is in app bunldle like,

```
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Amy.png"];
```

If you want to load `pdf` in `webview` from app bundle then you can do something like,

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourPdfName" ofType:@"pdf"];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webView loadRequest:request];
```

In short if you have files available in app bundle then you not need to copy it to `documentDirectory` because it will use double memory, you can direct used it from bundle.

Comment: If a user wants to open files not from App then also they can open it by document directory, So I used this. Thank You for your support !

Comment: user can open directly from app bundle there is no need to copy in documentdirectory if it is in app bundle!!!